# $arctan(z)$ and Riemann Surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts, branch-points

How do I link the complex trigonometric function arctan(z) and it's branch cuts and branch points with Riemann surfaces? I have seen the picture of the function's Riemann surface but I don't understand it very well.

Comment: Do you understand how the branch cuts and points are used to form a Riemann surface for a simpler function, for example $\sqrt z$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @RandyMarsh I have read something about it but I still don't understand.

Comment: @KingLogic I think that different surfaces cut at the origin. I. couldn't conclude much more.

Comment: Try first to understand how to form the Riemann surface for $\sqrt z$ and what is the motivation for constructing a Riemann surface in the first place. You may start with this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663665/understanding-the-riemann-surface-of-the-sqrtz

Comment: @RandyMarsh thank you. I think I understand it.